# How do I enable listing of zsh commands as you type

Tags: search, command, zsh, history

on one of my machines while setting up zsh I seem to have accidentally enabled a pretty useful feature. when I search through command history it actually lists all the matching commands as I type. How do I enable this in general?

Edit:

- Are you talking about searching through history with ctrl+r, i.e. bck-i-search?

  - Yes
- And what do you mean precisely by "it actually lists all the matching commands as I type"?

  - After ctrl+r brings up the search prompt, when I start typing, it brings up partial matches and lists them underneath the prompt.

Comment: Was it [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions)? It sounds similar, but I'm not sure what you mean exactly, and it's hard to enable by accident. Are you talking about searching through history with `ctrl`+`r`, i.e. `bck-i-search`? And what do you mean precisely by "it actually lists all the matching commands as I type"?